# Repetitive class (method/property) invoking in PHP

Tags: php, oop, class

The following is an excerpt from some code I wrote to assign the `$user->privilege` based on a method from that same class. It seems excessively repetitive, and I am wondering if there is something I can do to make it more readable -- given that I haven't seen this kind of repetition too much in codes I have looked at.

```
$user -> privileges = $user -> get_privileges ( $user -> username );
```

Comment: Why would you ever store the result of a function that is already accessible?  You're opening yourself up to inconsistency!  Also, consider setting `$user->username` as the default parameter for `get_privileges()` so you can omit it.

Comment: Yeah I like that idea much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look particularly repetitious to me, but it is a little unusual to be assigning an object's property based on a method outside the class.  Instead, this might be better handled inside the object constructor, eliminating the need for you to remember to set the property when coding:

```
class User {
    public $username;
    public $privileges;

    public function __construct() {
      // setup the user however that's done...

      // And assign privileges in the constructor
      $this->privileges = $this->get_privileges();
    }

    // In get_privilegs, rather than passing the username property,
    // just access it via $this->username.
    // Unless you need to use this method from time to time outside the class, it can be private
    private function get_privileges() {
      // Get privs for $this->username
    }
}
```

And as an alternative to `$this->privileges = $this->get_privileges();` called in the constructor, you might just set `$this->privileges` inside the `get_privileges()` method.  Then you can just call it as `$this->get_privileges()` in the constructor, no assignment necessary. Either way works.

Comment: As a newcomer to OOP, constructors still throw me for a loop sometimes. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: @DươngVăn You can do lots of useful work in the object constructor.

Comment: The second method seems like it would work better, since it is pulling values from $__COOKIES, which doesn't appear to work in constructors.

Comment: @DươngVăn `$_COOKIE` is available anywhere in the script, including the constructor. Make sure you have spelled it correctly - you called it `$__COOKIES` in your comment, but it has only one underscore and no S.

Comment: You are right, it is misspelled here, because I was referring to them as a collective entity of variables. It is a lack of precision :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this pattern a lot when a method is expensive and I can just store the result for the remainder of the request:

```
class User {
    protected $_privileges = null;

    public function getPrivileges() {
        if ($this->_privileges == null) {
            // code to populate privileges array
            $this->_privileges = $privileges;
        }

        return $this->_privileges;
    }
}
```

That way getPrivileges() will only do the hard work once and afterward it uses its own locally cached copy for the remainder of the request for that object instance.